# Django sub models do not appear in template

Tags: python, django, templates

Maybe I cannot see the forest because of all the trees, but I have a very strange issue.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from models import Question, QuestionAnswerAlloc, Section

def home(request):
    sections = Section.objects.all()
    for s in sections:
        questions = Question.objects.filter(section=s)
        for q in questions:
            answersalloc = QuestionAnswerAlloc.objects.filter(question=q)
            q.answers.append(answersalloc)
        s.questions.append(questions)

    return render(request, "questionaire/index.html", {'sections': sections})
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

from portal.models import Customer


class Section(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    weight = models.FloatField()
    maxscore = models.FloatField()

    questions = []

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.title)


class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section)
    weight = models.FloatField()

    answers = []

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Answer(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text="This has to be a value between 0 and 5")
    is_weighted = models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text="If this answer does not apply (N/a) it is not weighted!")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class QuestionAnswerAlloc(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Possible Answer"


class Report(models.Model):
    STATUS_STARTED = "started"
    STATUS_FIN = "finished"
    STATUS_INPROG = "inprogress"
    STATUS_ABORT = "aborted"

    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    started_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=150, default=STATUS_STARTED)
    guid = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class ReportAnswer(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    orignal_answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section)
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)

    points = models.FloatField()
    weight = models.FloatField()
    is_weighted = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

And my template:

```
{% for s in sections %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="FormStepInfo">
                        <p class="QuestionaireSectionTitle">{{s.title}}</p>
                        <p class="QuestionaireSectionDesc"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

                {% for q in s.questions %}
                <div class="row">
                    <hr/>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 quest-num">{{forloop.counter }}</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10 quest-title">
                        <label>
                            {{q.title}}
                        </label>
                        <br/>

                        <div class="CheckboxQuestion">
                            {% for a in q.answers %}
                            <label for=""><input type="radio" name="Q3" value="{{a.points}}" id="q3a1">{{a.title}}</label>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately, the question title is not shown, neither the answers. 
If I print out to sys.stderr i can see that there are questions assigned to the section. Am I missing something? I have restarted my "webserver", as I am using "python manage.py runserver" about 10 times and deleted my cache.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but I think you have to use `s.questions.extend(questions)` instead of `s.questions.append(questions)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a fairly large misunderstanding of class definitions in Python. Usually when you define an attribute at class level it is shared by all members of the class. Django fields do some special magic to ensure that the values are per-instance rather than per-class, but your `questions` and `answers` lists do not do that. So even if you could get your code to work, all the answers would be associated with all the questions.

Luckily there's no need to do any of this. Django provides you with reverse accessors that provide exactly what you need. So the view can be simplified to just:

```
def home(request):
    sections = Section.objects.all()
    return render(request, "questionaire/index.html", {'sections': sections})
```

and the view becomes:

```
{% for s in sections %}
   ...
   {% for q in s.question_set.all %}
       ...
       {% for a in q.questionansweralloc_set.all %}

       ...etc
```

Comment: Ok, that was ridiculously easy. Thank you for that!